The UK's population or The UK population
I always thought that the correct structure to talk about the population of a country is "Country + 's + population", for example, the UK's population and France's population.
However, searching Google for "the UK population", I also found that people do use it as well. link
So, why can't we say "France population", but we can say "the UK population"? Is that because "UK" in "the UK population" functions as an adjective?
P.S. I feel that this has something to do with the difference between using "population" to refer to "the people in the UK" and "the number of people in the UK".
You can discuss this using the two made-up examples below:

15% of the UK’s population were over 65 years of age in 1985.
 15% of the UK population were over 65 years of age in 1985


I'd be happy with either

Maybe the rule is that you can only use the country name attributively if it's an acronym? Like, "the UK population," "the US population," and "the EU population" all sound fine to me, but never "the Spain population," "the Germany population," or "the China population."

@QuackE.Duck - since I don't pronounce 'UK' as 'uck', 'US' as 'uss', and 'EU' as 'yew', I wouldn't call those three initialisms 'acronyms'. Also the European Union (English name) is not a 'country'. In the case of nations whose shortened, informal forms are not initialisms, I'd be able to use 'the' followed by the adjective form, ('the French population') or else 'the population of Name'.

@MichaelHarvey why are the initialisms ‘the UK’, ‘the US’ and ‘the EU’ informal? Also I would not say ’the American population’ even if it is grammatical, because of its ambiguity. Does it refer to only the United States or does it include Latin America/South America?

@Mari-LouA -nations and some other entities have formal or full names, e.g. The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, The United States of America, and 'European Union' in 24 languages, used in official documents, legislation, etc, and informal, sometimes initialised/abbreviated versions: UK, USA, EU (in France l'Union européenne or l'UE) for short in conversation, news stories, etc.

@Mari-LouA - I wouldn't say 'the American population; I'd say 'the US population' (I can use a definite article before an initialism). Regarding ambiguity, maybe you should write to the editor of the New York Times: 'The new census data covers the period up to July 2022. And while it shows the American population is older than it ever has been.' Or USAfacts.org: '9% of congresspeople are enrolled tribal members. Meanwhile, 19.1% of the American population is Hispanic, compared to 11.3% of Congress'. I agree that it is a woeful thing to assume that all 'Americans' live in the USA.

@MichaelHarvey I shall not write to the editor seeing as the NYT title says The U.S. Population Is Older Than It Has Ever Been and in the first paragraph it has ‘The median age in the United States reached a record high of 38.9 in 2022’ and further on it compares the median age of several states in the USA, that clearly disambiguates "American population" which is used only once in the entire article.

@Mari-LouA - OK, I'll concede that.

In AmE,   "the American {something}" typically refers to "the US {something}" and we use "the Central American..." and "the South American ..." and "the Canadian..." when not referring to the US. "North American" encompasses the US and Canada.  Isn't that the way it goes also in BrE?

Certainly in the US, American means pertaining to the US, and that usage is also very common in the UK. Canadians might object, and in some contexts (geography, anthropology, biology) it might be a problem, but not in politics, travel, etc. Although not wanting to upset Canadians, Mexicans, etc, is a valid reason for preferring US to American.

@TimR - it's the same in the UK. The default meaning of 'America' is 'the USA'.

Fifteen percent of the UK’s population were over 65 years of age in 1985. NOT: 15% at the beginning of a sentence.

@MichaelHarvey We may need to start spelling it with a K.

@TimR - Yes, I remember the first time around for that. One or three Ks.

Either is fine; just two different ways of referring to the same thing.

"The UK's population", using the possessive, is the population belonging to the UK.
"The UK population" is a noun phrase, using the name of the country as a modifier to label the noun 'population', distinguishing it from other populations that you may refer to.

As to why "France population" isn't acceptable - this is just due to linguistic conventions. We'd say either "France's population" or "the French population". The United Kingdom is a sovereign state made up of constituent countries and likewise, we would say "British population", not "Britain population". There isn't a single-word adjective that directly translates to "United Kingdom" in the same way "French" does for France and "British" does for Britain. And, as "UK" is commonly used as a label for those countries collectively it just works as a modifier in the noun phrase.

Do you have any idea why Grammarly suggests that I change were to was in my first example?

@anIELTSlearner Here's one for you: Percentages that are placed at the beginning of sentences should be written out in full. Fifteen percent of the population etc.

@lambie No that's nonsense - there's no such rule in grammar. It was pre-2019 Associated Press style guide rules to write it that way, but since then the % sign is preferred. Also, UK press guides prefer "per cent" when writing it out.

@anIELTSlearner You're naturally assuming that, because you're talking about people, you should use the plural "were". But you're not talking about people, you're talking about a percentage which is a single number. Percentages and other statistical numbers may not always represent whole numbers of people, especially when speaking about averages (eg the average family has 1.7 kids). In your case, it seems to refer to percentages of a fixed population in something like a poll or a census so to be honest your way is fine - it emphasises the individuality of the families.

@Astralbee "Most of the main English language style guides (i.e. The Chicago Manual of Style, The Associated Press Stylebook, the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association) agree that you should spell out numbers at the beginning of a sentence, rather than using a numeral". https://prowritingaid.com/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-a-number //That would include: The Financial Times and The Economist and most good US publications like the Atlantic Monthly and The New Yorker. This refers to written pieces/articles, NOT titles or captions. This is a style rule.

I have no idea why this is the case, but if we were talking about the United States of America then I would readily accept "the US population" but "the USA population" would sound wrong. Not sure if that's just me.

@kaya3 I agree, and again it's down to accepted linguistic conventions. The "US" is an abbreviation of an initialism. It's not the official name of a country but it works great as a modifier

This is nitpicky, but I'm compelled to point out that, while British is the correct demonym, if you say Britain, you are technically excluding Northern Ireland. Depending on the political situation, people can take offense to inadvertent exclusions like this, although non-native English speakers are likely to get some leeway.

@WeiwenNg I know that national identity is very important to certain individuals but you're not technically correct. 'Britain' is actually Great Britain, and includes Scotland and Wales. I am English and British, just as a Scot is Scottish and British. The United Kingdom includes Great Britain and Northern Ireland. My country of residence is the UK but my nationality is British.
